# Java DefaultTableModel

Tags: java

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    DefaultTableModel Samplemodel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    Samplemodel.setRowCount(0);


    FileInputStream excelFIS = null;
    BufferedInputStream excelBIS = null;
    XSSFWorkbook excelImportWorkBook = null;

    String defaultCurrentDirectoryPath = "D:\\Downloads";
    JFileChooser excelFileChooser = new JFileChooser(defaultCurrentDirectoryPath);
    excelFileChooser.setDialogTitle("Select Excel File");
    FileNameExtensionFilter dist = new FileNameExtensionFilter("EXCEL FILES", "xls", "xlsx", "xlsm");
    excelFileChooser.setFileFilter(dist);
    int excelChooser = excelFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (excelChooser == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            File excelFile = excelFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            excelFIS = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
            excelBIS = new BufferedInputStream(excelFIS);
            excelImportWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelBIS);
            XSSFSheet excelSheet = excelImportWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < excelSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                XSSFRow excelRow = excelSheet.getRow(i);

                XSSFCell excelStudentID = excelRow.getCell(0);
                XSSFCell excelStudentName = excelRow.getCell(1);
                XSSFCell excelCourse = excelRow.getCell(2);
                XSSFCell excelYearLevel = excelRow.getCell(3);
                XSSFCell excelContactNumber = excelRow.getCell(4);
                XSSFCell excelBalance = excelRow.getCell(5);


                Samplemodel.addRow(new Object[] {
                    excelStudentID,
                    excelStudentName,
                    excelCourse,
                    excelYearLevel,
                    excelContactNumber,
                    excelBalance
                });



            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Excel File is successfully Imported");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Sample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

The error is:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel cannot be cast to class
> Sample$DefaultTableModel (javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel is in
> module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap'; Sample$DefaultTableModel is
> in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: I'm trying to import data on jtable

Comment: The exception message indicates that you are trying to cast an instance of `javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel` to a type with the same name but a different package(`Sample$DefaultTableModel`).  Check your class imports to make sure you are importing the correct type.  If you need to work with both types in this class then you'll need to handle one (or both) by fully qualified type name.

Answer (score 0):

It seams you have declared a class (or interface) `DefaultTableModel` inside a class `Sample` and you must have imported that class instead of `javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel`.